# Where to download list of all common stocks traded on NYSE, NASDAQ and AMEX?

Tags: data, market-data

I have a very basic data question: how to get a list of all common stocks traded on NYSE, NASDAQ and AMEX? I would need to be able to get the approximate list of common stocks as is available in Telechart... I can not get this data at [eoddata](http://www.eoddata.com), for example...

I would like to calculate market breadth indicators and would like to find out how many of common stocks traded were up or down 4% (breakouts/breakdowns) (Cl-Lag(Cl) > 0.04 (4% breakout), Cl-Lag(Cl) < -0.04 (4% breakdown)), how many of common stocks traded are down/up 25% in quarter etc.

My first problem is how to get a list of symbols with only common stocks (no ETFs).

Comment: Hi Samo, welcome to quant.SE and thanks for your question. Please consider registering in order to edit and respond to answers and to gain further privileges.

Comment: nasdaq site is extremely dated. bloomberg is up to date.

Comment: NASDAQ site has been updating this entire time.  sure the site design is old, but the data is good.

Comment: In 2019, the data is here: ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/symboldirectory/

Comment: Try this API endpoint to lookup tickers https://rapidapi.com/logicione/api/stock-ticker-security-and-company-search-database?endpoint=apiendpoint_aac710aa-f501-497e-8cc7-8c552d40f955  and this endpoint https://rapidapi.com/logicione/api/stock-ticker-security-and-company-search-database?endpoint=apiendpoint_da310f0a-27d1-43b7-8392-14d09ba83502  to lookup/check S&P500 traded (i.e. actively traded) companies. You can try the API for 50 req/day free. For more calls pay a small amount.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338608/download-all-stock-symbol-list-of-a-market

Comment: `https://pkgstore.datahub.io/core/nasdaq-listings/nasdaq-listed-symbols_json/data/5c10087ff8d283899b99f1c126361fa7/nasdaq-listed-symbols_json.json`

`https://pkgstore.datahub.io/JohnSnowLabs/list-of-companies-in-the-new-york-stock-exchange/list-of-companies-in-the-new-york-stock-exchange-csv_json/data/0026360bbb7be2840f71db501b9bdede/list-of-companies-in-the-new-york-stock-exchange-csv_json.json`

Answer (score 120):

NASDAQ makes this information available via FTP and they update it every night. Log into `ftp.nasdaqtrader.com` anonymously. Look in the directory `SymbolDirectory`. You'll notice two files: `nasdaqlisted.txt` and `otherlisted.txt`. These two files will give you the entire list of tradeable symbols, where they are listed, their name/description, and an indicator as to whether they are an ETF.

Given this list, which you can pull each night, you can then query Yahoo to obtain the necessary data to calculate your statistics.

UPDATE: More information about these files and their fields can be found [here](http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=symboldirdefs).

Comment: Very nice! I'll have to add a function to TTR to access these files.

Comment: Does Yahoo allow you to run a script to do thousands of HTML fetches against their servers?  I know some web sites will ban your IP if you try that.

Comment: @pacoverflow They do, at the very least, allow ~7500 sequential individual requests. It is also possible to download data for up to 200 symbols from Yahoo! in one request.

Comment: ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/
ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt
ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/otherlisted.txt

Comment: I created an account on this site just to upvote this answer (and the question). I can't believe how hard this type of information is to find, reliably.

Comment: Jan-2020 version: https://github.com/pyrytakala/public/blob/master/fina/nasdaqlisted.txt

Comment: I'm looking at https://www.advfn.com/amex/americanstockexchange.asp?companies=M and I don't see MXM listed on either of those files listed on the ftp

Comment: nevermind.  I seee that advfn has outdated listings which MXM is (hasn't traded since 2017)

Comment: otherlisted is fully contained within nasdaqtraded.txt (compared with R's setdiff).  So if looking for all 3 markets, just download that.  I compared amex and nyse symbols from eoddata to confirm that at least 90% of the symbols were found in nasdaqtraded.txt

Comment: The nasdaqlisted.txt and otherlisted.txt include all the traded securities, which means ETFs are included. I wonder if you have any thoughts about how can I just include common stock, rather than ETFs?

Answer (score 31):

Slightly ugly bash one-liner for a sorted JSON array:

`echo "[\"$(echo -n "$(echo -en "$(curl -s --compressed 'ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/nasdaqlisted.txt' | tail -n+2 | head -n-1 | perl -pe 's/ //g' | tr '|' ' ' | awk '{printf $1" "} {print $4}')\n$(curl -s --compressed 'ftp://ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/SymbolDirectory/otherlisted.txt' | tail -n+2 | head -n-1 | perl -pe 's/ //g' | tr '|' ' ' | awk '{printf $1" "} {print $7}')" | grep -v 'Y$' | awk '{print $1}' | grep -v '[^a-zA-Z]' | sort)" | perl -pe 's/\n/","/g')\"]"`

---

EDIT: Filtered out test stocks

Comment: I just had a nerdgasm

Comment: +2 for taking out the Test stock listings.

Comment: Got this: `head: illegal line count -- -1
head: illegal line count -- -1
["-n ",""]`

Comment: @Elimination I think you have to put a space between the -n -1 arguments for non-GNU utilities.  On my Mac, I got it to work using ghead, gmail, gawk, etc. from Macports.

Answer (score 20):

[Bloomberg Open Symbology](http://bsym.bloomberg.com/sym/) has this list. Look in the Common Stock precanned file. This will have a bit more data than you probably need as it has a separate entry and unique id for each place an equity is traded. However it is probably the highest quality list available for free anywhere.

As for filtering ETFs are broken out in a separate file (Equity_ETP) so you simply need to filter by exchange.

Update November 2017: BSYM is no more and its replacement does not have prebuilt files as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is great because it has all securities globally - I'd found it difficult to get non-US symbols before this.

Comment: @fantabolous Can you provide an example for how to use this to get all tickers? Can't figure out how to use it.

Comment: @Hamidam E.g. if you want all HK common stock, from the left panel of the link above choose Market Sector: Equity, Sec Type: Common Stock, Country: Hong Kong. Click Submit. Then click "Excel" in top right corner. Done.

Comment: Also, for equities if you select a country (not exchange) and then deselect `All Exchanges` it'll give you only the primary exchange.

Comment: Not working....

Comment: @hyprfrcb Yeah, BSYM is gone. Updated the answer to denote this.

Comment: this link is dead

Answer (score 18):

You can download all stocks on the three exchanges listed in your question from the NASDAQ website: http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx.

It looks like removing those entries with an industry of "N/A" will eliminate ETFs and other funds from the list.

Comment: This link doesn't work anymore since NASDAQ decided to push in a new update to their webpage.

Comment: @troymyname00  The revised url is  https://old.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx  that seems to work.

Comment: The URL has been updated again. It is now at https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener  Also, the format returned from the web request has changed to JSON.

Answer (score 9):

The `stockSymbols` function in the R package [TTR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TTR/index.html) pulls the data from nasdaq.com that @bellamyj mentioned.  It also attempts to convert the symbols to a format acceptable to Yahoo Finance.

That said, I'm not certain how to filter this list for only common stocks.  There are 1275 securities with "n/a" Sector or Industry, leaving ~5000.  Perhaps the remaining categories in Sectors and Industries can help you further refine the list.

Comment: I have a problem using this function, in fact I only get gibberish. I posted on [R-Sig-Finance] on the matter.

Comment: @Owe: I [answered on R-SIG-Finance](https://mailman.stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2011q3/008360.html).  Basically, the file changed and I haven't pushed the update to CRAN yet.  The [R-Forge version of TTR](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/ttr) works.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the fast reply and for writing this function.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using this [API](https://unibit.ai/api/docs/V2.0/stock_coverage) called Stock Coverage from unibit. It covers around 70,000 stocks from 49 exchanges. Though I'm not sure if it is the most updated. A few recent IPOs can be found in the list.

The ticker standard seem to complies with Yahoo's and it works with many of the other APIs in their site.

All their listed tickers can be found on this [public domain](https://public.acho.io/embed/9bffe75f11a5a99349359c98c74b9b0ba41cf563b351ffbb7ecc19614706f827861e5171a35b6f8296aa1d43a7558cfb978ae74ac969094d1c991bf7d8c8ca9f).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an existing brokerage account or perhaps a data provider you're subscribed to? I was able to previously receive a complete list of stocks for the full Equities universe on all the US exchanges from algoseek.com

Comment: SEC maintains a free downloadable list of companies.  https://www.sec.gov/file/company-tickers or directly download the json file at https://www.sec.gov/files/company_tickers.json