# How to get a list of stocks symbol of a specific exchange?

Tags: r

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to download list of all common stocks traded on NYSE, NASDAQ and AMEX?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1640/where-to-download-list-of-all-common-stocks-traded-on-nyse-nasdaq-and-amex)

Is it possible to download a list of stocks that belong to a specific exchange (e.g. NASDAQ, AMEX, NYSE)?  The `tseries` package has a function to download the price history of a stock, but how to get all the stocks of an exchange?

Comment: Related to: [How can i see all available data series from quantmod package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219308/how-can-i-see-all-available-data-series-from-quantmod-package) and [Downloading Yahoo stock prices in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507744/downloading-yahoo-stock-prices-in-r)

Comment: @Joshua I have seen the second link, it looks awesome, but it only works for NASDAQ, NYSE and AMEX. is there another function to downaload other exchanges?

Comment: @Joshua is still TTR package broken in R-Cran?

Comment: Unfortunately, TTR on CRAN is still broken.  I don't know of a function to download symbols from any other exchanges.

Comment: JOshua i have seen i can use it for these three exchanges and i also can use TTR to get historical price from yahoo, right?

Comment: There's `TTR::getYahooData`, but I would just use `quantmod::getSymbols`.

Comment: @Joshua, why use a different function of a different library if TTF has it ?

Comment: -1 and vote to close. This question has already been answered [here](http://quant.stackexchange.com/q/1640/1106)

Comment: Agree, vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

I think you are confused about "markets". Of the three you listed, only NASDAQ is an exchange, the other two are information services. For the three major US exchanges, you go to:
 (NASDAQ, AMEX, NYSE):

http://www.nasdaq.com/screening/company-list.aspx

Pick the one you are interested in and answer their silly robot barrier "puzzle" and download the csv file, in which the ticker symbol is the first column.

Edit: With TTR_0.20-3 from r-forge, the list appears more complete than with the prior version:

```
require(TTR)
SYMs <- TTR::stockSymbols()
#Fetching AMEX symbols...
#Fetching NASDAQ symbols...
#Fetching NYSE symbols...
 table(SYMs$Exchange)

##  AMEX NASDAQ   NYSE 
#   308   2820   3261
```

Whereas the csv file from NASDAQ for NASDAQ had 2820 symbols. <strike>On the other hand the TTR authors may have eliminated some of the duplicates, warrants or outdated symbols.</strike>

Comment: `TTR::stockSymbols` does this for you.  See the two links in my comment to the OP.

Comment: yes i think it too. Good!

Comment: @Dwin: looks like you're using TTR_0.20-2.  `stockSymbols` is broken in that version.  I really need to push an update to CRAN.  Also, it doesn't eliminate any symbols.

Comment: Yes. My system reported that as the current CRAN version.