# where can I get a list of all yahoo finance stocks symbols

Tags: yahoofinance

I remember having seen that somewhere, I can't find it any more. 
Anyone knows how can I get all the list of stocks on Yahoo finance.

Or even all american stocks, maybe Russell 1000/2000/3000...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to download list of all common stocks traded on NYSE, NASDAQ and AMEX?](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1640/where-to-download-list-of-all-common-stocks-traded-on-nyse-nasdaq-and-amex)

Comment: If you want daily updated data, might want to look into this API https://rapidapi.com/logicione/api/stock-ticker-security-and-company-search-database?endpoint=apiendpoint_45e4f2f7-2a95-411d-96b3-81fc51c78079

Answer (score 11, accepted):

BATS has a nice downloadable file: 
http://batstrading.com/market_data/listed_symbols/

There's a CS and XML. They have 7,000 stocks in that list. Good stocks, not OTC.

Comment: that's a cool one, it doesn't have non US, or I couldn't find non-us. But I still accepted the answer since I only mentioned Russell index. Anything similar for the rest of the world? (UK, Australia ...)

Comment: No that I've found. US Markets have the best data sources due to popularity.

Comment: After downloading the csv I only have 359 symbols though

Answer (score 8):

For American stocks: if you are using Python 3, you can first, from a terminal, do

```
pip install get-all-tickers
```

then

```
from get_all_tickers import get_tickers as gt

list_of_tickers = gt.get_tickers()
# or if you want to save them to a CSV file
get.save_tickers()
```

Alternatively, you can clone the file from https://github.com/shilewenuw/get_all_tickers/blob/master/get_all_tickers/tickers.csv

Comment: This source is no longer valid.

Answer (score 4):

You can get a list of tickers for free using Finnhub's API.

You just need to request a free API key.

Check out the following documentation:
https://finnhub.io/docs/api#stock-symbols

```python
#pip install finnhub-python
import pandas as pd
import finnhub

#list of available exchanges

df=pd.read_html("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I3pBxjfXB056-g_JYf_6o3Rns3BV2kMGG1nCatb91ls/edit#gid=0")
df1=df[0]
exc=df1.loc[:,"A"].dropna()

exclist=[]
for i in exc:
    exclist.append(str(i))
exclist=exclist[1:] #take out "name" from the list

#retrieve tickers from every exchange available
tickers=[]
finnhub_client = finnhub.Client(api_key="c46qn9iad3iagvmhdk7g")
for exchange in exclist:
    listofdicts=finnhub_client.stock_symbols(exchange)
    for dicts in listofdicts:
        tickers.append(dicts['symbol'])

print("You just got a list of %s tickers worldwide." % len(tickers), tickers)
```

Comment: needed to run this on mac: `/Applications/Python 3.10/Install Certificates.command`

Comment: FinnhubAPIException(status_code: 401): You don't have access to this resource.

Answer (score 3):

I have found this tool: https://github.com/Benny-/Yahoo-ticker-symbol-downloader

It uses the search api https://finance.yahoo.com/_finance_doubledown/api/resource/searchassist;searchTerm=s6s?device=console&returnMeta=true

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Closed its API, we are also downloading manually all the symbols for our use. Also we are sharing it wil all on https://github.com/stockdatalab/YAHOO-FINANCE-SCREENER-SYMBOLS-AND-HISTORICAL-DATA. you can download from above link.

Google Yahoo both not providing symbol list any more also Google providing historical data only for one year of any company.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this - it pulls down 400000 tickers.
https://github.com/mlapenna7/yh_symbol_universe

Answer (score 0):

YQL seems to fail at queries with like '%AM%' and also there is no other way to get list of all stock symbols. but i think this can do the trick..

select * from yahoo.finance.industry where id in (1,2,3....260)

this will give you list of companies and there symbols. 
start with 
select * from yahoo.finance.industry where id in (112)
and see if it works.

Comment: can you give me an example of how to use YQL? is that using a link of some sort?

Comment: YQL was retired in 2019: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Query_Language

Answer (score 0):

For common equities, you the find the list in [here](https://public.acho.io/embed/9bffe75f11a5a99349359c98c74b9b0ba41cf563b351ffbb7ecc19614706f827861e5171a35b6f8296aa1d43a7558cfb978ae74ac969094d1c991bf7d8c8ca9f).

There are 69k stocks from 49 exchanges.

Also, these tickers comply with Yahoo Finance's standard.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to scrape all symbols present in that yahoo-finance screener. You can simply create a screener [here](https://finance.yahoo.com/screener)

I have modified the code a little bit because yahoo-finance was returning an empty 404 response when working with the python requests module. Similar to this [issue / solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47506205/14137254)

Here is the complete working code.

```python
import requests
import json
import time

# Modify BASE_URL accordingly
BASE_URL = "https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/unsaved/79fce2f7-82fe-49ec-8098-88add84138ec?dependentField=sector&dependentValues=&offset=OFFSET&count=COUNT"

cnt = 100
offset = 0
flag = 1
temp  = 10
name_to_symbol = []
total = 0

while flag > 0:
    url = BASE_URL.replace("OFFSET", str(offset))
    url = url.replace("COUNT",str(cnt))
    offset += cnt
    
    response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom'})
    s = str(response.text)
    jsonArrayStart = s.find('"results":{"rows"') + 18
    jsonArrayEnd = jsonArrayStart + 1

    while s[jsonArrayEnd] != ']':
        jsonArrayEnd += 1
    
    jsonArrayString = s[jsonArrayStart: jsonArrayEnd+1]
    jsonArray = json.loads(jsonArrayString)
    if len(jsonArray) != cnt:
        flag = 0
    
    total += len(jsonArray)
    for obj in jsonArray:
        if 'longName' in obj:
            name_to_symbol.append([obj['symbol'], obj['longName']])
        elif 'shortName' in obj:
            name_to_symbol.append([obj['symbol'], obj['shortName']])
        else:
            name_to_symbol.append([obj['symbol'], obj['symbol']])
    time.sleep(10)
    
name_to_symbol
```

P.S - Sorry for the late response. Also, I have rejected all the edits as they were irrelevant and I have fixed the code now. In future I would recommend commenting on the post instead of suggesting an improper edit

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It was working earlier but it now throws an error. Can you please fix it. I checked the json it returns now is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 0):

#### Here's the best link i've found

[Best Link I've Found](https://investexcel.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Yahoo-Ticker-Symbols-September-2017.zip)

Comment: That's from 2017.