# Is NASDAQ file "nasdaqtraded.txt" a list of all common stocks traded on NYSE, NASDAQ and AMEX?

Tags: data, market-data

A prior post had stated how to get a list of all common stocks traded on NYSE, NASDAQ and AMEX - via NASDAQ site at `ftp.nasdaqtrader.com` in `SymbolDirectory` and the two files: `nasdaqlisted.txt` and `otherlisted.txt` (see [Where to download list of all common stocks traded on NYSE, NASDAQ and AMEX?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1640/where-to-download-list-of-all-common-stocks-traded-on-nyse-nasdaq-and-amex)).

In that same FTP location I see now a file named `nasdaqtraded.txt` at 
`ftp.nasdaqtrader.com/symboldirectory`.

Does anyone know if the `nasdaqtraded.txt` file have all the same info `nasdaqlisted.txt` and `otherlisted.txt` has? Does it have more or less info? Updated daily like the other two? It'd be easier to look at this one file than parsing two files to get a list of all common stock. I cannot find info on this file at NASDAQ so not sure of it's purpose.

Answer (score 4):

The only files you need are 'nasdaqlisted.txt' and 'otherlisted.txt'. Simply merge and sort the files.

The 'nasdaqtraded.txt' should be the total of 'nasdaqlisted.txt' and 'otherlisted.txt'. And 99.99% of the time it is. However, I have found a few, rare exceptions where one or two symbols were missing.

It is best to just download, merge, and sort the listed files.

According to the definition page, "The symbol directory files are updated periodically through-out each day."

http://www.nasdaqtrader.com/trader.aspx?id=symboldirdefs