# How to check if a symbol is a Common Stock (Equity)?

Tags: equities, etf

I had read this [Where to download list of all common stocks traded on NYSE, NASDAQ and AMEX?](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1640/where-to-download-list-of-all-common-stocks-traded-on-nyse-nasdaq-and-amex).

I know the `ETF` field of `nasdaqlisted.txt` indicate whether it is an ETF, but it is not always correct.

For example: `DGLD` - `VelocityShares 3x Inverse Gold ETN Linked to the S&P GSCI Gold Index ER`

It's an ETF on Yahoo Finance, but it's **NOT** an ETF in `nasdaqlisted.txt`.

So, what's the correct(best) way to check if a symbol is a `Equity` or not? In other words, check if it's a ETF or not?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is an ETN which strictly speaking is not an ETF (although many people mix the two up). So I would say on this one it is Yahoo Finance which is wrong. Do you have other examples of discrepancy?

Comment: @noob2 Although you are right, but how can I filter equity from `nasdaqlisted.txt`? I only need equities.

Comment: If you have access to WRDS ad CRSP, you can download all stock data and keep items with share code 10 and 11 (common equity) and exchange code 1, 2 and 3 (NYSE, AMEX, NASDAQ).

Comment: If you are going to use this data, you might need a Blacklist (exclusion list) of things which are not equities, you could start by including in it all things which have ' ETN' in the name, but you might discover other things later that you also want to exclude. ADRs? REITs? Unfortunately you will have to maintain this list manually when new bad things pop up.

Comment: @KeSchn Can anyone access them?

Comment: @JokeHuang  no unfortunately not. Many universities provide access to wrds. If you’re in a job, your employer may do? I don’t know. But CRSP is _the_ data source for US stock data for academic research.